# SD Card mounted but not accessible in Finder (OS 10.10.5)

Tags: macos, disk-utility, sd-card

On an early 2015 MacBook Air running 10.10.5, Finder will not show SD cards, despite the disk showing up in Disk Utility.  In Finder preferences, I have set external disks to be shown on the Desktop and in the sidebar.  So far, I've tested multiple SD cards (FAT and exFAT, just in case) both in the card slot and in an external SD-to-USB card reader; I've verified all of the cards and card readers on another computer, so I don't believe it's a hardware issue.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Can you post the output of the following command please?: `defaults read com.apple.finder|grep ShowRemovable`

Comment: same problem here and with usb pen drive too!
suddenly last morning it stopped working for no reason ! MacBookPro/running Yosemite 10.10.5.

Comment: Hi @WilliamTFroggard, thanks for the input.  `grep` doesn't return anything for `ShowRemovable`.  If I look at the full output of `defaults read com.apple.finder`, I can find `ShowHardDrivesOnDesktop = 1`, but nothing regarding external drives.

Comment: Further update: the issue seems to actually be that external devices are not automatically mounting.  I've enabled "Automatically open read-only images" as well as "...read/write images" in Disk Utility Preferences, but that hasn't helped thus far.